# Adding a timeline style graphic using r-highcharter

Tags: r, data-visualization, timeserieschart, r-highcharter

I have hydro-graphs that I am creating using *highcharter* library in R. 
I want to add another variable(or adjust value with any existing variable) to this graph as a timeline (as shown in the image).
The value table for this variable is a time series data frame as well but, the values are as "0" and "1"
where "0" shows no flood and "1" shows flood. 
So I want to show (only value "1") this as flood duration as a timeline.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
Year_2005_rain <- subset(Seven, 
                         time >= as.Date('2005-04-01') & 
                         time <= as.Date('2005-10-31'))
Year_2005_flow<- subset(Seven_flow, 
                        time >= as.Date('2005-04-01') & 
                        time <= as.Date('2005-10-31'))
Year_2005_inflow<- subset(Seven_inflow, 
                          time >= as.Date('2005-04-01') & 
                          time <= as.Date('2005-10-31'))

merge1_05 <- merge(Year_2005_rain,
                   Year_2005_flow,
                   Year_2005_inflow, by="time")

names(Year_2005_rain) <- names(Year_2005_flow) <- names(Year_2005_inflow)
merge1_05 <- rbind(Year_2005_rain, Year_2005_flow,Year_2005_inflow)

colnames(merge1_05)[colnames(merge1_05)=="time"] <- "date"
colnames(merge1_05)[colnames(merge1_05)=="Discharge"] <- "value"

merge1_05$date = as.Date(merge1_05$date, format = "%Y/%m/%d")    
merge1_05$variable <- c(rep("rain", 214), rep("discharge", 214), rep("inflow", 214))

hc_14<- highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "rainfall depth (mm)"), reversed = TRUE), 
                     list(title = list(text = "flow (m3/s)"), opposite = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = filter(merge1_05, variable == "rain") %>% 
                mutate(value = value) %>% .$value, type = "column") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = filter(merge1_05, variable == "discharge") %>% .$value,   
                type = "spline", yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = filter(merge1_05, variable == "inflow") %>% .$value,  
                type = "spline", yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = merge1_05$date, title = list(text = "date"))

  hc_14
```

[image: High Chart graph]

[Link to data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I76ASCvu7V7Iv-MjeVAAXONnyJqCyOWi)

In the data folder, Flood.csv has the data that I want to add as a new variable

Comment: You should add your code to the question instead of put it in the link. To draw the horizontal line/segment, I think you need to do something similar to this http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html#hc_xaxis-and-hc_yaxis

Comment: @Tung Thank you for your response again. While this can be an option but for that, I would have to normalize the value "1" somehow so that it can fall somewhere in the middle. But since I have to create multiple graphs for some years so it can be difficult.

Comment: First, please provide proper credit to the author of the codes.  They are free to use, but with proper statement of credits.  Second, it will not too hard to add another column in the dataset.  Then replace the number 1 to a good number to show in the plot.  I don't think it is too hard for that.